# Dataframe analysis by sample name and date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, split

I have a dataframe of groundwater sample results. The table could look like this:

| Well Number | Sampling Date | Compound | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-01 | a | 0.5 |
| A | 2020-01-01 | b | 0.3 |
| A | 2020-01-01 | a | 0.6 |
| A | 2020-07-01 | c | 0.1 |
| A | 2020-07-01 | c | 0.1 |
| A | 2020-07-01 | c | 0.4 |
| B | 2020-02-01 | a | 0.1 |
| B | 2020-08-01 | c | 0.1 |

Now, I would like to analyse the data for each well and each sampling date. Specifically, I would like to determine, whether the wells have at least 2 compounds that have been measured with a result over 0.2 on the same date.

If yes, I would like to store this information. So, in this example well A has 3 compounds with a value of over 0.2 on 2020-01-01. So the stored information should look something like:

A 2020-01-01 -> true

A 2020-07-01 -> false

B 2020-02-01 -> false

B 2020-08-01 -> false

My table has thousnds of rows and non-linear data intervals. So the time and quantity of the measurements vary for each well.

How can I go through the data and make this anaysis and store it? I tried the split function to split the set into smaller sets by date and well number. But I did not really now how to work with the output format. Also, I remember in python I think I did something similar with a loop function (for i in...). Would that also work in R? And if yes, how?

Thank you very much even just for reading through my question :)

Comment: I used loops and if statements now to go through the lines and to check if the current line is different to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether `all` values per group are above 0.2 per `case_when`. You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Sampling_date) %>%
  mutate(info = case_when(all(Result > 0.20) ~ "true", TRUE ~ "false"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Sampling_date [4]
  Well_Number Sampling_date Compound Result info 
  <chr>       <chr>         <chr>     <dbl> <chr>
1 A           2020-01-01    a           0.5 true 
2 A           2020-01-01    b           0.3 true 
3 A           2020-01-01    a           0.6 true 
4 A           2020-07-01    c           0.1 false
5 A           2020-07-01    c           0.1 false
6 A           2020-07-01    c           0.4 false
7 B           2020-02-01    a           0.1 false
8 B           2020-08-01    c           0.1 false
```